# How to update a table in Oracle using a join on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, syntax, updating

I have an update query where I am trying to update a field but for more than one record, I am trying a join but it doesn't work. Below I get multiple values that come back from the select statement but I think my syntax is incorrect below.

```
     UPDATE sku@bn2 x 
     INNER JOIN (
     select g.prev_perm_ret, g.itm_cd
     from gm_prc_reg_prc_items g, sku@bn2 b
     where g.itm_cd=b.stylecode
     and b.storecode=00000
     and g.prev_perm_ret<>b.listprice
     and g.prev_perm_ret>g.ret_prc
     and b.sellprice=b.listprice
     ) y ON x.stylecode=g.itm_cd
     SET x.listprice=y.prev_perm_ret
```

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE INTO sku@bn2 x 
USING (
     select g.prev_perm_ret, g.itm_cd
     from gm_prc_reg_prc_items g, sku@bn2 b
     where g.itm_cd=b.stylecode
     and b.storecode=00000
     and g.prev_perm_ret<>b.listprice
     and g.prev_perm_ret>g.ret_prc
     and b.sellprice=b.listprice
     ) y ON x.stylecode=Y.itm_cd
when matched then update
set x.listprice=y.prev_perm_ret`

Comment: Actually that didn't work but thanks anyway.  I was able to resolve this myself just now.